# Find anchor tag using href value and change href value with new href value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

This is the html code:

```
<td>
<a class="buttontext" href="/kkdmpcu/control/MilkDeliveryScheduleReport.txt?shipmentId=10306&amp;reportTypeFlag=milkDeliverySchedule" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10306);" title="Milk Delivery Schedule">Delivery Schedule</a>
</td>
<td>
<a class="buttontext" href="/kkdmpcu/control/KVGenerateTruckSheet.txt?shipmentId=10306&amp;reportTypeFlag=abstract" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, 10306);" title="Abstract Report">Route Abstract Report</a>
</td>
```

I have the href value. Using href value I should find the anchor tag and change the href value to new value using jQuery. This is the code I currently have which is not working:

```
$('a[href$=(existingUrl)]'); // existingUrl is the href value I have
    .attr('href', resultUrl);  // resultUrl is the url that I need to replace with existingUrl.
  
//The whole code I have Right now

function setSelectedRoute(existingUrl, shipmentId) {
         
        var updatedUrl = existingUrl.toString();
        var facilityIndex = updatedUrl.indexOf("facilityId");
        
        if(facilityIndex > 0){
            updatedUrl = updatedUrl.substring(0, facilityIndex -1);
        }
        var form = $("input[value=" + shipmentId + "]").parent();
        var routeId = form.find("option:selected").text();
        var resultUrl = updatedUrl + "&facilityId=" + routeId;
        alert(resultUrl);
        
        $('a[href='+existingUrl+']').attr('href', resultUrl);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not the `href` attribute, it is the `a` tag itself, that is first mistake, therefore `existingUrl` will get the object instead.

change the code like

```
function setSelectedRoute(existingUrl, shipmentId) {

        var updatedUrl = $(existingUrl).attr('href'); // first instance
        // or var updatedUrl = existingUrl.getAttribute('href');

        var facilityIndex = updatedUrl.indexOf("facilityId");

        if(facilityIndex > 0){
            updatedUrl = updatedUrl.substring(0, facilityIndex -1);
        }
        var form = $("input[value=" + shipmentId + "]").parent();
        var routeId = form.find("option:selected").text();
        var resultUrl = updatedUrl + "&facilityId=" + routeId;
        alert(resultUrl);

        $('a[href="'+$(existingUrl).attr('href')+'"]').attr('href', resultUrl);  //second instance
    }
```

for the second instance, you can directly use `existingUrl`

```
$(existingUrl).attr('href', resultUrl);
```

Comment: really so geek :) Thank you. "$(existingUrl).attr('href', resultUrl);" works for me. In case of first Instance I am getting the following error in firefox firebug.. TypeError: existingUrl.attr is not a function[Break On This Error] var updatedUrl = existingUrl.attr('href'); // first instance

Comment: @ so geek.. So nice of you.. Thank you.. Now I have another problem.. Don't know which one to use.. ;) lol..

Answer (score 1):

You should not use  semicolon between the selector and the `attr` method, also if `existingUrl` is a variable you should concatenate it, try this:

```
$('a[href="'+existingUrl+'"]').attr('href', resultUrl);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I tried this and I am getting following error in firebug. 'uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=https://localhost:18443/kkdmpcu/control/KVGenerateTruckSheet.txt?shipmentId=10300&reportTypeFlag=trucksheet]'. In the form I have no. of tr's and no. of td's but url is unique. Is this error due to unrecognized td or tr? this is the whole code I have

Comment: You´re just missing the quotes; `$('a[href="' + existingUrl + '"]').attr('href', resultUrl);`. See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I am calling function setSelectedRoute from html onclick event. something like this: action="javascript:setSelectedRoute(this, ${shipmentId});" ("this" is giving href value).

Comment: @Vicky Are you sure that the `href` is correct? try the updated answer.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for the link. very helpful.. I am sure I have correct href. I tried this. Now I don't get any error, but it's still not redirecting with new href.

Comment: @Vicky Your post doesn´t say anything about a redirect. Try describing you´re goal with the function and I´m sure someone will be able to guide you in the right direction.